# Proving $R(m + 1, n) \geqslant R(m, n)$ for all $m, n \geqslant 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

> Is the Ramsey number $R(m + 1, n) \geqslant R(m, n)$ for all $m, n \geqslant 2$? 
>   Briefly justify your answer.

Can anyone help me with this please? Many thanks.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question in future posts.

Comment: Also please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website.